# How do I transfer a date-time value from a Pandas data frame to a new row in Smartsheet using the Python API?

Tags: python, pandas, smartsheet-api

I have some data in an excel csv file, and I have copied it into a Pandas data frame:

```py
data_frame = pd.read_csv(EXCEL_FILE)
data_frame = data_frame.fillna('')
```

One of the fields in the csv has this format: "3/17/2022 10:59:00 AM" and when transferred to the data frame it shows '3/17/2022 10:59'. So I convert it to what I think is the right Smartsheet format with this line, 'Created' being the column name:

```py
data_frame['Created'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['Created']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00Z")
```

and ends up being '2022-03-17T10:00:00Z'.

When I create the smartsheet row using a loop and

```py
data_dict = data_frame.to_dict('index')
rowsToAdd = []
for i, i in data_dict.items():
    new_row = smartsheet_client.models.Row()
    new_row.to_top = True
    for k, v in i.items():
        new_cell = smartsheet_client.models.Cell()
        new_cell.column_id = column_map[k]
        new_cell.object_value = v
        new_row.cells.append(new_cell)
        rowsToAdd.append(new_row)
        result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(SHEET_TO_MODIFY, rowsToAdd)
```

the date cell shows in smartsheet as '2022-03-17T10:00:00Z'. And if I use a formula like =TODAY() - [Created Date]@row, I get an error #INVALID OPERATION.

How can I get it right?

If I use "%Y-%m-%d" it does not work, I get 2022-03-17 but it still throws an error in the sheet.

If I do something like

```py
new_row.cells.append({'column_id':7150106886596484,'value':"6/7/2022",'strict':False})
```

it works, but to do that I would need to split the loop and it may overcomplicate things.

I checked the column properties and it is indeed a Date column, and the column has other Dates there and they do work with the formula.  If I check the box for restricting values to only dates, the script throws an error.  If the selection box is on one of the new fields, I even see a blue "calendar" icon next to the date:
[showing calendar icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVCRx.png)

I tried adding an extra column at the end, making sure it is a Date type and having nothing else there, and I get the same errors.  I converted the Data Frame to an array and used those fields as input, using dfvalues = data_frame.values, same thing.

One more thing, smartsheet is forcing me to use "objectValue' instead of 'value' as the attribute, even though the documentation says I should use 'value'.

Not sure if it helps, I printed the data types for the data_frame columns, and they all come up as 'object'

I have some updates:
I hard coded the string '2022-06-07T15:00:00Z', but the problem is still there. I also changed the data frame column type of "Created" from 'object' to 'string' with

```py
data_frame['Created'] = data_frame['Created'].astype('string')
```

but still nothing.

**I did get an improvement:**
If after the script has ran, and I find all the dates in the '2022-06-07T15:00:00Z' format with the formula in error, I change the data type of the "Created Date" column in smartsheet to Text/Number and then back to Date, everything falls into place, the field show up as June 7 instead of 2022-06-07T15:00:00Z, and the date formula in the other column works.
I guess I'll do that for now, it does not take a long time, but I'll keep poking to see what the problem is with the script.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional info. I added additional info to my answer (**<Update_2>** and **<Update_3>** before I noticed your updates here in your post. See that new info below.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I've been able to reproduce your issue, and I think I've identified the cause.

First of all, the date format you're using (e.g., `2022-03-17T10:00:00Z`) looks like the correct format for dates in Smartsheet.

Seems like the problem is that the column you're inserting your date value into is of type `Text/Number`. It should instead be of type `Date`. You should be able to change the column type in the Smartsheet app via the UI.

In the following screenshot:

- `Date in Text/Number column` shows how the value `2022-03-17T10:00:00Z` renders in a `Text/Number` column.
- `Date in Date column` shows how that same value `2022-03-17T10:00:00Z` renders in a `Date` column.
- `Formula using Date in Date column value` shows the result of the formula `=TODAY() - [Date in Date column]@row`. Note that because that formula returns an integer, the column must be of type `Text/Number` in order to not return an error.
- `Formula using Date in Text/Number column value` shows the result of the formula `=TODAY() - [Date in Text/Number column]1`. It's resulting in an error because the formula is trying to subtract a `Text/Number` value from a `Date` value.

[image: Smartsheet data]

Try changing the column where you're inserting the date value to be of type `Date` and I suspect that'll resolve your issue. Additionally, if you have another column in your sheet where you're using formulas like `=TODAY() - [Created date]1` -- make sure that column is of type `Text/Number`, since such formulas will return a numeric value.

**<Update_1>**

**Additional testing of your scenario**

To programmatically test your scenario, I used Postman to update my test sheet with a date string formatted exactly like the one you say you're inserting (`2022-01-17T10:00:00Z`). The following request puts that date in a **Text/Number** column in my sheet (`columnId: 1467329779394436`) and in a **Date** column in my sheet (`columnId: 6783215096620932`):

```
POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/3932034054809476/rows
[
    {
        "id": "3812039265019780", 
        "cells": [
            {"columnId": "1467329779394436", "value": "2022-01-17T10:00:00Z"},
            {"columnId": "6783215096620932", "value": "2022-01-17T10:00:00Z"}
        ]
    }
]
```

The API response is as follows. Notice that the **Text/Number** column (`columnId: 1467329779394436`) has a `displayValue` attribute indicating that it's going to display the full string, while the **Date** column (`columnId: 6783215096620932`) just has a `value` attribute set to the date.

```
{
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "resultCode": 0,
    "result": [
        {
        ....
            "cells": [
                {
                    "columnId": 1467329779394436,
                    "value": "2022-01-17T10:00:00Z",
                    "displayValue": "2022-01-17T10:00:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "columnId": 6783215096620932,
                    "value": "2022-01-17"
                },
        ...
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 120
}
```

And when I visually inspect the sheet in Smartsheet where the update was applied, I see the same thing I saw before -- inserting the UTC date string in a **Text/Number** type column displays that value as the string (`2022-01-17T10:00:00Z`), whereas inserting the UTC date string in a **Date** type column displays the date (`1/17/22`).

[image: smartsheet row 1 after update]

This seems to verify my original assessment of your issue:

1. The format of the date value you're inserting (`2022-03-17T10:00:00Z`) is valid.
2. Inserting such a value into a **Text/Number** column will indeed result in the issue you've described (i.e., the string `2022-03-17T10:00:00Z` being displayed instead of the date, and being unable to perform date-related calculations on that value -- because Smartsheet is treating it as Text/Number data, not Date data).

**How to verify / set column type in Smartsheet:**

Just seeing a value in a Sheet that looks like a date doesn't necessarily mean that the Column Type is set to **Date**. i.e., it's possible for a column with type `Text/Number` to contain values that visually look like dates (e.g., you visually see `6/7/22` in the sheet). So, be sure to examine the Column Properties to verify that Column Type is actually set to **Date**. You can do so as follows:

- Double-click the column header or right-click and choose **Edit Column Properties**. The **Column Type** value needs to be `Date` for the column where you're programmatically inserting the date value (e.g., `2022-03-17T10:00:00Z`):

[image: column properties]

**<\Update_1>**

**<Update_2>**

**Additional troubleshooting suggestions**

I'm pretty sure the problem you're describing is caused by one of the following things:

1. The column type of the column that you're trying to update isn't configured properly (i.e., isn't of type **Date**).

OR

2. The data that you're trying to add to a column of type **Date** is formatted incorrectly.

We've already explored option 1 a bit, and based on your feedback in the comments, it seems like the column is correctly configured as type **Date**.

So, let's explore option 2 a bit. We need to confirm that the value you're trying to insert in the column of type **Date** is a `string` value in format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`

If you're able to capture a trace of the outbound request JSON that's being sent to Smartsheet, please update your post above to add that JSON and add a comment to this answer to let me know once that info is there.

If you don't know how to capture a trace of the outbound request JSON that's being sent to Smartsheet, then let's troubleshoot another way. I'd suggest that you update the code that's inserting the date value from the dataframe into Smartsheet to instead insert the (hardcoded) date string `'2022-06-07T15:00:00Z'`. i.e., change your code as follows:

```
new_row.cells.append({'column_id':column_ids[m],'objectValue':'2022-06-07T15:00:00Z','strict':True})
smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(SHEET_TO_MODIFY,new_row)
```

If running this code (with the hardcoded string value in format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` specifying the date) is successful -- then that indicates that the value stored in `data_frame.loc[n][m]` is ***NOT*** formatted like Smartsheet requires date values to be formatted (i.e., Smartsheet requires date values to be specified as a `string` value in format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`).

Can you give this a try and let me know the outcome by adding a comment below?

ETA -- based on the info you recently added to your original post `"I printed the data types for the data_frame columns, and they all come up as 'object'"` -- I suspect this is the problem. You likely need to convert the object in the dataframe that contains the date to a `string` value in format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` before you try inserting the value into the Smartsheet sheet.

**</Update_2>**

**<Update_3>**

**Incorrect property name?**

One more idea -- I just noticed that in the code you posted, you're setting a property called `objectValue` (to the value that contains your datetime string) -- I don't think that's the correct property name. Try changing `objectValue` to be `value` instead:

```
new_row.cells.append({'column_id':column_ids[m],'value':data_frame.loc[n][m],'strict':True})
smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(SHEET_TO_MODIFY,new_row)
```

**</Update_3>**

**<Update_4>**

**Change your approach for appending cells to the row**

Okay, I think I've finally gotten to the bottom of this (hopefully!).

Let's assume I start with the following code to translate column names to column IDs and create a `DataFrame` with some sample data to populate a few columns in my sheet -- including a date column that I'll try to populate with the `string` value `2022-03-17T10:00:00Z` as specified in the data frame.

```
sheet_id = 3932034054809476
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

# translate column names to column id
column_map = {}
for column in sheet.columns:
    column_map[column.title] = column.id

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date in Date column':['2022-03-17T10:00:00Z'],
                'item_id': [111111],
                'item_color': ['red'],
                'item_location': ['office']})

data_dict = df.to_dict('index')

rowsToAdd = []
```

If I try your approach (as follows), it results in a `400 Bad Request` error with the message `"The value \"2022-03-17T10:00:00Z\" could not be saved in column \"Date in Date column\". This column is restricted to DATE values only."`.

```
#----
# YOUR ORIGINAL APPROACH (using objectValue property)
#----

# each object in data_dict represents 1 row of data
for i, i in data_dict.items():

    # create a new row object
    new_row = smartsheet_client.models.Row()
    new_row.to_top = True

    # for each key value pair, create & add a cell to the row object
    for k, v in i.items():

        new_row.cells.append({'column_id':column_map[k],'objectValue':v,'strict':False})

smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheet_id,new_row)
```

The root cause of this error (and the reason that you're having to use the `objectValue` property instead of the `value` property) is that the following line of code (from the above sample code) is appending a JSON object, and not a `cell` object as defined by the Python SDK:

```
new_row.cells.append({'column_id':column_map[k],'objectValue':v,'strict':False})
```

Instead of appending a JSON object like you're doing -- for each cell in the row you want to update, you should construct a `cell` object and append the `cell` object to the row. The following code shows this (successful) approach.

```
#---
# THE CORRECT APPROACH (constructing a cell object & using value property)
#---

# each object in data_dict represents 1 row of data
for i, i in data_dict.items():

    # create a new row object
    new_row = smartsheet_client.models.Row()
    new_row.to_top = True

    # for each key value pair, create & add a cell to the row object
    for k, v in i.items():

        # create the cell object and populate with value
        new_cell = smartsheet_client.models.Cell()
        new_cell.column_id = column_map[k]
        new_cell.value = v

        # add the cell object to the row object
        new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

    # add the row object to the collection of rows
    rowsToAdd.append(new_row)
            
result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheet_id, rowsToAdd)
```

Please note that this sample code is designed to add multiple rows of data (if multiple rows of data are present in the data frame). I realize your code structure may differ, depending on your data and your objective -- but the bottom line is this: for each row you want to update, you need to construct a `cell` object for each cell you want to update, and then append each `cell` object to the row. (Do not simply try to append raw JSON data as your original post shows.)

Hope this helps! Please give this a try and add a comment on this answer to let me know the result.

**</Update_4>**

**<Update_5>**

**Final Update:** I've implemented the scenario you've described, from start to finish, and successfully added rows to Smartsheet where dates are formatted properly in the column of type `Date`. I'll describe my process in entirety here, and hopefully you can spot the difference between my (successful) approach and your (unsuccessful) approach.

**Source data (Excel):**

I created a new Excel file with 2 columns -- `item_id` and `my_date`, added two rows of data to the file, and then saved the file in `.csv` format. The resulting `.csv` file looks like this:

[image: csv data]

**Smartsheet sheet:**

I created a new Smartsheet for this test, with two columns (`item_id` and `my_date`), where the `my_date` column is defined as type `Date` and `Restrict to dates only` is enabled.

[image: new sheet in Smartsheet]

**Code:**

In my code, I read data from the `.csv` file into a dataframe, reformat date values in the dataframe to comply with Smartsheet date format, and then add data from the dataframe to the Smartsheet sheet.

```
# test sheet
sheet_id = 2946133799528324
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

# translate column names to column id
column_map = {}
for column in sheet.columns:
    column_map[column.title] = column.id

# create dataframe from Excel file data
path_to_file = 'test.csv'
data_frame = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)
data_frame = data_frame.fillna('')

# examine data (before reformatting dates)
print(data_frame)
## RESULTS:
#         item_id                my_date
#     0         1   3/7/2022 10:59:00 AM
#     1         2  9/18/2022 10:59:00 AM

# reformat dates
data_frame['my_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['my_date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00Z")

# examine data (after reformatting dates)
print(data_frame)
## RESULTS:
    #     item_id               my_date
    # 0         1  2022-03-07T10:00:00Z
    # 1         2  2022-09-18T10:00:00Z

data_dict = data_frame.to_dict('index')

rowsToAdd = []

# each object in data_dict represents 1 row of data
for i, i in data_dict.items():

    # create a new row object
    new_row = smartsheet_client.models.Row()
    new_row.to_top = True

    # for each key value pair, create & add a cell to the row object
    for k, v in i.items():

        # create the cell object and populate with value
        new_cell = smartsheet_client.models.Cell()
        new_cell.column_id = column_map[k]
        new_cell.value = v

        # add the cell object to the row object
        new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

    # add the row object to the collection of rows
    rowsToAdd.append(new_row)
            
result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheet_id, rowsToAdd)
```

**Result:**

When I run the code, it completes successfully and the following data is displayed in Smartsheet:

[image: data in Smartsheet]

**</Update_5>**

Comment: Hi Kim, thanks for answering!  The column is a Date column and it already contains other dates (mostly the ones I corrected manually from the script that is not working).  And the field where the formula goes is of type Text/Number.  I suspect the problem has something to do with the date value I'm inserting overriding the column type, if that is possible.  The column does have a couple of text fields, maybe that's throwing things off?

Comment: don't consider the comment about the column having text fields, in the test page I'm using all the fields are dates and the problem is still there.

Comment: I've added additional information to the end of my answer -- starting with **Additional testing of your scenario** and then followed by **How to verify / set column type in Smartsheet**.  Please review and verify the type of the column where you're inserting the date value (using instructions I've provided for doing so).

Comment: Hi Kim, I checked the column and it does say Date, and I even get a little blue "calendar" icon next to the value, showing it really is considering it as a Date.  I did not have the "Restrict to dates only" option checked, so I checked it and ran the script again.  I got this error: The value \"2022-06-07T15:00:00Z\" could not be saved in column \"Created Date\". This column is restricted to DATE values only."

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've updated my answer with more info. Please see the section **<Update_2> (Additional troubleshooting suggestions)** and let me know what you find. And one other question for you: is it true that the column `Created Date` that's referenced in the error message you posted in your previous comment is a column (of type **Date**) that you ***manually created*** in the sheet yourself -- and NOT the system-generated `Created` column that Smartsheet auto-populates for every row when it gets created?

Comment: I've added yet more info -- see the **<Update_3> (Incorrect property name?)** section in my answer.

Comment: about the column names: "Created" is the name of the column in the csv file, and "Created Date" is the column in the smartsheet, which should eventually hold the same data.  I had been working with this smartsheet before, updating it manually and copying the data from the csv file.  Then I started using a Python script to automate that, so the columns have the correct format because when doing it manually it worked.  The script basically reads the csv file and the smartsheet, and deletes the tasks that have been completed and adds the new tasks that the csv file brings.

Comment: about another of your comments, I have to use the property objectValue because if I use value I get:  Exception has occurred: ApiError
{"result": {"code": 1235, "errorCode": 1235, "message": "Value is not supported for this column type. Use objectValue instead.", "name": "ApiError", "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "refId": "106yso1wfh1qf", "shouldRetry": false, "statusCode": 400}}.

Comment: I think I've figured out your problem.  It has to do with the way you're appending cells to the new row. I'll update my answer momentarily and will add another comment here when it's been updated. Stay tuned...

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to add **<Update_4> (Change your approach for appending cells to the row)**. Please review and give it a try and let me know the outcome.

Comment: So, I tried your latest suggestion.  If I use your code and the simplified data frame, it works.  But if I use my data frame, it goes back to saying I need to use objectValue.  But if I use objectValue I get "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value.".  And if I use object_value it does not throw an exception but again places the date value in full.

Comment: To assist any further I'd need to see your code in its entirety (i.e., all the code involved with building the data frame and inserting data from the data frame into Smartsheet). If you want to update your original post with that info, I can see if I can spot what you're doing wrong. Now that we have a working example (i.e., the working sample code in my **<Update_4>**), it's just a matter of trying to design your code in a similar fashion to that.

Comment: Hi Kim, I have updated the post with the code to build the data frame, though I don't think it will be too useful.  After that I move some columns around, add an empty column, and change the index, but I don't touch the date column.  The rest is the code in the post.  You mentioned capturing "a trace of the outbound request JSON that's being sent to Smartsheet", I can't seem to find how to do it, do you know of a tutorial you could point me to?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add **<Update_5> (Final Update)**, which describes in detail exactly how I've been able to successfully implement the scenario you've described. This is unfortunately as much help as I'm able to offer here. Hopefully you'll be able to spot the difference between your (unsuccessful) approach and my (successful) approach.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to the format of the date, it needs to be constructed as ISO format before

[Smartsheet Dates format](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#dates-and-times)

I can see in the error message you are getting that ISO has not been constructed yet, it should look something like: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ and the error value shows as 'value':"6/7/2022"

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for contributing!  The last comment showing the "6/7/2022" hard coded directly in the script as a text string actually works, the one that is not working is the one the script brings from the pandas data frame.  I of course need to use this one and not the hard coded option.

Answer (score 0):

Make the date you want to update Smartsheet with ISO format.